# Increase speed of the code which makes many api calls and stores all data into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I wrote a code which takes identifier number and make request to specific API and returns concerning data related to this identifier number. The code run through dataframe and takes the identifier numbers (approximately 600) and returns concerning information and converts into pandas dataframe. Finally, all dataframes are concatenated into one dataframe. Code is running super slow. Is there any ways how to make it faster. I am not confident in python and will appreciate if you can share solution code.
Code:

```
file = dataframe

list_df = []

for index,row in file.iterrows():

    url = "https://some_api/?eni_number="+str(row['id'])+"&apikey=some_apikey"

    payload={}
    headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    a = json.loads(response.text)

    df_index = json_normalize(a, 'vessels')
    df_index['eni_number'] = row['id']

    list_df.append(df_index)

    #print(df_index)

total = pd.concat(list_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bottleneck here is that HTTP requests are executed synchronously, one after the other. So most of the time is wasted waiting for responses from the server.

You may have better results by using an asynchronous approach, for example using [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) to execute all HTTP requests in parallel:

```py
import grequests

ids = dataframe["id"].to_list()
urls = [f"https://some_api/?eni_number={id}&apikey=some_apikey" for id in ids]

payload = {}
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
requests = (grequests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload) for url in urls)

responses = grequests.map(requests)  # execute all requests in parallel

list_df = []
for id, response in zip(ids, responses):
    a = json.loads(response.text)
    df_index = json_normalize(a, 'vessels')
    df_index['eni_number'] = id

    list_df.append(df_index)

total = pd.concat(list_df)
```

Comment: I have this error:The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Comment: This error seems related with Jupyter notebooks, can you try with a usual python script ?

Comment: I run the code on aws ec2 instance, and it was the same